# Escaping string array index in link_to - Laravel

Tags: php, escaping, laravel-4

Sorry I've been banging my head for a while on this, would like some help now

The following doesn't work because the single quotes for the array index are being interpreted as the ending of the url, so I get a `syntax error: unexpected 'year'`

```
<li>{{ link_to('admin/showGroups/$year['year']', $year['year']) }}</li>
```

Edit:

Output for the above is:

```
<li><?php echo link_to('admin/showGroups/$year['year']', $year['year']); ?></li>
```

I've tried:

(double quotes around the url):

```
<li>{{ link_to("admin/showGroups/$year['year']", $year['year']) }}</li>
```

(escaping the index single quotes with `\`)

```
<li>{{ link_to('admin/showGroups/$year[\'year\']', $year['year']) }}</li>
```

output for the above is:

```
<li><a href="http://localhost/rootfolder/public/admin/showGroups/$year['year']">2015</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you provide the output HTML for this element as well from view-source?

Comment: @Lee Yes I've done it now, but for the double quotes it gives a syntax error (don't know why you can't double quote the entire string but you can single quote?), as well as the original single quoted method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the curly braces like php open/close tags and everything should work.

```
<li>{{ link_to('admin/showGroups/'.$year['year'], $year['year']) }}</li>
```

Theres a lot of useful info on interpolation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) if you want to read up on the topic